# IPhone 4S, Apple ID not working

Tags: apple-id

My IPhone won't let me create an Apple ID, it says that my Email is already in use. I made a new Hotmail account but it's still saying that it's already in use, which is impossible.

Comment: I'm locking this as an example off-topic question. See [Why we're not customer support for company X or product Y](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y)